# Find the maximum number

Tags: c, max

I need to find the maximum number from file `in.txt` with content: `12 7 -14 3 -8 10` and then write it to file `out.txt`. Here is my full code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int N, max;
  FILE*F;
  F = fopen("in.txt", "r");
  FILE*G;
  G = fopen("out.txt", "w");
  fscanf(F, "%d", &max);
  while (feof(F)) {
    fscanf(F, "%d", &N);
    if (max < N)
      max = N;
  }
  printf("max=%d", max);
  fprintf(G, "%d", max);
  fclose(F);
  fclose(G);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: **Format your code.** so, C or C++? In C++, you could use `<fstream>` and `std::max_element`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, Unfortunately, `std::max_element` requires storing everything and then iterating through it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Max and Min floating numbers from a file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377214/finding-max-and-min-floating-numbers-from-a-file-in-c)

Comment: @chris nope, `std::istream_iterator`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, It needs a ForwardIterator because it returns the iterator to the element, which doesn't work so well in the case of input on demand.

Comment: @chris I've tried it and it worked just fine. [Link](http://ideone.com/sMm8am)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, I have a striking feeling it's undefined behaviour, but compiles because all of the operations are syntactically valid (as opposed to, say, needing `--it` and giving something with just `++it`).

Comment: @chris if that's the case, it means that `std::max_element` can't be used directly with files, which is horrible.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, [Well, I asked the lounge.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19863381#19863381)

Comment: @chris Thanks. I'm amending my answer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, Look a bit further :/

Comment: @chris so they said it's undecidable. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect use of `feof()`.

Do not use `feof()` to check if additional input is available.  `feof()` reports that the *previous* I/O operation resulted in the end-of-file condition.

IOW, check the results of your input operations like `fscanf()`.

Suggest:

```
int MaxFound = 0;
while (fscanf(F, "%d", &N) == 1) {
  if (MaxFound) {
    if (N > Max) {
      Max = N;
    }
  } else {
    MaxFound = 1;
    Max = N;
  }
}
if (MaxFound) {
  printf("max=%d\n", max);
} else {
  puts("max not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++14, you could use `std::max_element` directly with `std::istream_iterator`:

```
std::ifstream inf("in.txt");
auto it = std::max_element(std::istream_iterator<int>(inf), std::istream_iterator<int>());

if (it != std::istream_iterator<int>()) {
    std::ofstream outf("out.txt");
    outf << *it << std::endl;
}
```

In C++11 and earlier, this seems to be undefined behavior (because `istream_iterator` is an `InputIterator`, but `max_element` expects a `ForwardIterator`), so in those variations of the language you will need to read the file in a container (most like `std::vector`) before using `max_element`.